# Selecting from a second bd_table based on array results PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Please be patient with me with this question as I'm fairly new to PHP (apart from contact forms and login forms etc) but I really need some help relating to Arrays and data held in 2 separate tables.  The scenario is that I am building an events section in a website & I am holding the data in an 'events' table:

event_id, event_name, event_time, etc, etc

I then have a table (event_followers) for followers of the events:

```
event_id | user_id
event_id | user_id
event_id | user_id
```

What i need to do is select all of the events that a particular user is following and show it as an array and then somehow get specific information about each of the events that is listed in the array/result.  Any ways this can be done?

I'm sorry if this is basic php but as I said I'm pretty new to it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$query  = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM events 
                       LEFT JOIN  event_followers as fol ON event_followers.event_id = events.event_id 
                       WHERE event_followers.user_id='".$user_id "'");
while($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
   print_r($row);
}
```

`mysql`* functions are deprecated, so use `mysqli_`* or `PDO`, But I am not good at that so I written the code in `mysql`.

Comment: Thank you, I've been reading about the changes to mysql_ functions - Not sure how it will effect all those websites not built with mysqli or PDO but I'm guessing it won't be pretty - Thanks again anyway